# populating a tuple with model objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple checklist in my personal info form that users can fill. this checklist gets its choices from tuple and that tuple gets its items from another model called field like this:

```
class Field(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='default')
    title = CharField(max_length=32)


INTERESTS = (Field.objects.values_list('slug', 'title'))
```

everything works just fine. however, when I add a new field object, INTERESTS tuple wont get updated without migrations. how can I update my tuple without any migrations? is it even possible?

this is my simplified models:

```
class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    interests = MultiSelectField(choices=INTERESTS, blank=True)
```

and my form:

```
class Interests(forms.ModelForm):
    interests = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=INTERESTS)

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalInfo
        fields = ['interests']
```

Comment: Is this for a ModelForm, can you show where it's used? You can use a `forms.ModelChoiceField` to generate a field that takes it's options from a model

Comment: yes I used it for a ModelForm. I need checkboxes for my form. I used django-multiselectfield for it not modelchoicefield. cause I need the user to choose multiple options, not just one

Comment: Can you add your models and form to the question

Comment: I updated it. check it out

Comment: Why use `MultiSelectField` instead of a `ManyToManyField`? It would simplify a lot of what you are doing and wouldn't require this manual generation of choices: `interests = models.ManyToManyField(Field)`

Comment: I was planning to. but I thought maybe we could fix this one instead. so you are telling me there is no way?

Comment: There's always a way, it's just a matter of making things easy for yourself

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer, but it's too long for a comment. I dont know how much you "simplified the model", but you should change the `interest` into a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships). Right now if any value will be deleted from `Field`, you will get invalid data in the database. If you will use `ManyToManyField`, it will it will make sure your DB data consistent will be consistent. So your model will look like this:

```
class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Field)
```

After doing this, using the `ModelForm` should handle the data in form for you without doing anything "manually" there.